# ipad splash screen doesn't rotate

Tags: ios, splash-screen

I would like to be able to rotate my splash screen on my ipad to landscape right and left. 
i have enabled landscape right and left orientation in my .plist file. i've added 4 files for the LandscapeRight and LandscapeLeft:

```
Default-LandscapeRight@2x~ipad.png
Default-LandscapeLeft@2x~ipad.png
Default-LandscapeRight~ipad.png 
Default-LandscapeLeft~ipad.png
```

although this shouldn't matter, in my rootviewcontroller i've got:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft); 
    return ( UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape( interfaceOrientation ) );
}
```

The splash screen loads, but it doesn't rotate.
what am i doing wrong?

Comment: you can use custom splash screen for that.

Comment: @SarafarazBabi please detail. I thought defining landscape left and right splash screens was custom splash screen

Comment: I means you can create one class for splash screen and pass it as rootviewcontroller and after 1 or 2 sec just push your homeview controller...and manage shouldautorotate in splash screen class...Got it?

Comment: @SarafarazBabi good idea! Thanks! I would like to know though why isn't my way working?

Comment: Does the correct screen load, or are you just missing rotation when it's already visible?

Comment: @Eiko the correct screen doesn't load (i.e. if i hold it right and left it's the same thing, it doesn't choose the correct splash)

Answer (score 1):

As I Know Device does not recognise the Orientation in the duration of Splash Image.These SPlash images Default-LandscapeRight@2x~ipad.png
Default-LandscapeLeft@2x~ipad.png
Default-LandscapeRight~ipad.png  recognise when app going to launch device then device takes Appropriate Splash Image.
Default-LandscapeLeft~ipad.png.

You can do the Alternate solution if you interested.and this is just my concept nothing more

1 create the UIIMageView for this Purpose and Add it as SUbview to Window.

2  Set iamge to that UIIMageView.

3 Set Sleep method for 3-4 seconds. like sleep(4).

4 As call goes to RootViewController manage the Orientation of Image.

like below method
this is the Method suppose you have defind In The AppDelegate class will manage the Image Orientation.

```
 -(void)checkOrientationforSplash:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrentaion
    {
if (splashImageView.hidden==FALSE) {
    if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad){
    if (interfaceOrentaion==UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait|| interfaceOrentaion==UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
        UIImage *image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Default-Portrait.png"];
        splashImageView.frame=CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, image.size.width, image.size.height);
        [splashImageView setImage:image];

    }
    else {
        UIImage *image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Default-Landscape.png"];
        splashImageView.frame=CGRectMake(0.0, 20.0, image.size.width, image.size.height);
        [splashImageView setImage:image];
    }
       }
```

}

5 You can Manage That Image Form in the Mid of App Instaltion, RoortViewController.

6 Remove That Splash Image At Specific Point.

```
 -(void)removeSplash
   {
     [splashImageView setHidden:YES];
   }
```

I hope it'll  help you.

Comment: this is a good idea! Thanks! btw my splash screen doesn't start the way it should neither! (i.e. if i hold it right and left it's the same thing, it doesn't choose the correct splash).